# Average time between 2 hours in R

Tags: r, datetime

I need to calculate the `date+time` between 2 given columns with also `date+time`.
If my dataset is something like this:

```
d <- data.frame("date1" = c("2021-02-06 02:00:00", "2021-02-06 05:00:00", "2021-02-06 07:00:00"), 
                "date2" = c("2021-02-06 03:00:00", "2021-02-06 05:30:00", "2021-02-06 07:40:00"))
d$date1 <- as.POSIXct(d$date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d$date2 <- as.POSIXct(d$date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

> d                    
                date1               date2
1 2021-02-06 02:00:00 2021-02-06 03:00:00
2 2021-02-06 05:00:00 2021-02-06 05:30:00
3 2021-02-06 07:00:00 2021-02-06 07:45:00
```

The desired output must be:

```
                date1               date2    date_inthemiddle
1 2021-02-06 02:00:00 2021-02-06 03:00:00 2021-02-06 02:30:00
2 2021-02-06 05:00:00 2021-02-06 05:30:00 2021-02-06 05:15:00
3 2021-02-06 07:00:00 2021-02-06 07:40:00 2021-02-06 07:20:00
```

I haven't really found anything to do such thing easily...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame("date1" = c("2021-02-06 02:00:00", "2021-02-06 05:00:00", "2021-02-06 07:00:00"), 
                "date2" = c("2021-02-06 03:00:00", "2021-02-06 05:30:00", "2021-02-06 07:40:00"))
d$date1 <- as.POSIXct(d$date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d$date2 <- as.POSIXct(d$date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


mutate(d, res = difftime(date2, date1) / 2 + date1)
#>                 date1               date2                 res
#> 1 2021-02-06 02:00:00 2021-02-06 03:00:00 2021-02-06 02:30:00
#> 2 2021-02-06 05:00:00 2021-02-06 05:30:00 2021-02-06 05:15:00
#> 3 2021-02-06 07:00:00 2021-02-06 07:40:00 2021-02-06 07:20:00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Take average of `date2 - date1` and add it to `date1`.

```
transform(d, result = date1 + (date2 - date1)/2)

#                date1               date2              result
#1 2021-02-06 02:00:00 2021-02-06 03:00:00 2021-02-06 02:30:00
#2 2021-02-06 05:00:00 2021-02-06 05:30:00 2021-02-06 05:15:00
#3 2021-02-06 07:00:00 2021-02-06 07:40:00 2021-02-06 07:20:00
```